# How to use bash -c with arguments

Tags: bash, shell

Does anyone know why the output of the first snippet is `bash` instead of `test`?

```
$ bash -c "echo $0 $1" "test"
bash
```

```
$ bash -c 'echo $0' "test"
test
```

How can I use `bash -c` with double quotes and positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. ?

Comment: `bash -c "echo \$0" "test"`

Comment: Your use-case is unclear (to me). What output do you expect from the first command? (Please edit your Q rather than reply in comments). As 0stone0 indicates, it's all a matter of obeying the rules of quoting. Setting $1 doesn't happen in your first sample, it is already set, when the parent rocess gets started. Good luck.